# Has anyone manage to Logstash-output-gelf plugin with TCP connection?

Tags: tcp, logstash, elastic-stack, graylog, gelf

I am trying to use Logstash-output-gelf plugin with TCP connection to graylog2.
I use logstash version 5.4.2, Graylog 2.2

I have used the below output settings

```
output {
gelf{
host =>"127.0.0.1" // i have changed the ip address. The actual IP connects to a server on the network
port => 15205
}
```

According to the code change found on [Github](https://github.com/logstash-plugins/logstash-output-gelf/commit/29bd5d088aa871cbd6555c75b94f64fc19dae47b), You can see that the code expects a paramert @protocol, however when I pass protoco => "TCP" in the output, I get an error in the config file.

Can someone please explain to me what I am doing wrong here?

Thanks

Comment: Did you have any luck with this? I'm also interested in sending gelf output through TCP.

Comment: No not yet. I am using UDP for now.. Busy with some other work at the moment. So will start looking into it again. The Github article says, that there is support for TCP, but there is no example anywhere on how to do it.

Answer (score 2):

I've figured it out. I'm not sure which version of logstash-output-gelf plugins comes with your version of logstash but gelf TCP output was introduced in 3.0.0

I've installed the newest version (currently 3.1.3) manually:

```
logstash-plugin install --version 3.1.3 logstash-output-gelf
```

And it worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 0):

I've only been able to make it work with a graylog GELF UDP input